# JS: Array print the values that repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, duplicates

I need to print the duplicates from an array.

For example, given the following array and index, the function will print `6,23,33,100`.

```
var array = [3,6,67,6,23,11,100,8,93,0,17,24,7,1,33,45,28,33,23,12,99,100];
```

Apparently we need to do it using two 'while loops'.

Im looking for a solution, but more importantly an explanation.
Links are very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to use "two while loops"? Otherwise the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59612071/1244884) from @Dince12 does the job well.

Comment: Yes, for practice we should use a loop within a loop (is it called Nested loops (?))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most elegant and *efficient* solution is to use a `while` loop which iterates the array only once, so, we have `O(N)` complexity.

For this, we need to declare an `hash` which keeps the number of *occurencies* for each *array's item*. If we found a `duplicate` one then we *store* it in `duplicates` array.

```js
var arr = [3,6,67,6,23,11,100,8,93,0,17,24,7,1,33,45,28,33,23,12,99,100], i = 0, hash = {}, duplicates = [];
while(i < arr.length){
  hash[arr[i]] = hash[arr[i]] ? hash[arr[i]] += 1 : 1;
  if (hash[arr[i]] === 2) 
    duplicates.push(arr[i])
  i++;
}

console.log(duplicates)
```

Comment: thanks a lot Michai, works really good! 
what should I search for to find explanation for this method?

Comment: You need to read about arrays methods in javascript, especially.

Comment: my mentor just told me I need to do it with the 'even-if' function, instead of 'hash[arr[i]] = hash[arr[i]] ? hash[arr[i]] += 1 : 1;'

Comment: The you can use `if(!hash[arr[i]) hash[arr[i]] = 1 else hash[arr[i]]++`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) methods.

```js
var array = [3,6,67,6,23,11,100,8,93,0,17,24,7,1,33,45,28,33,23,12,99,100];
console.log(array.filter((a,b,c) => c.indexOf(a) !== b));
```

a -> is the value being passed in the arrow function.

b -> is the index being passed in.

c -> is the whole array being passed in.

This line is filtering the array based on, if the original array has a value (argument a) whose index does not match the given index passed in through the arrow function (argument b).

Comment: OP is probably looking for something much more basic. They are a beginner and according to the task, the solution is intended to use regular loops.

Comment: @VLAZ How is this more complex than any other answers so far (mine included) ;) ?

Comment: @customcommander we're talking about somebody who is trying to learn *loops*. The iteration methods are a generalisation of loop logic and thus a concept that should come after. We don't start doing algebra in school straight from multiplication by skipping addition.

Answer (score 0):

A good sample and explanation can be found here... [W3Resource](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-array-exercise-20.php)

Futhermore to assist in understanding the two major components of the code the Object...
[Working with objects - Javascipt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

and Arrays...[Javascipt Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

For the shortest approach, you could take a closure

```
(s =>                           )(       )
```

with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
(s =>                           )(new Set)
```

and a check. If a value is already seen, then take this value

```
(s => v => s.has(v)             )(new Set)
```

or add the value to the set and return `false`, because a not seen value should not in the result set.

```
(s => v =>             !s.add(v))(new Set)
```

```js
var array = [3, 6, 67, 6, 23, 11, 100, 8, 93, 0, 17, 24, 7, 1, 33, 45, 28, 33, 23, 12, 99, 100],
    duplicates = array.filter((s => v => s.has(v) || !s.add(v))(new Set));

console.log(duplicates);
```